# Is it possible to use config transformations in an ASP.Net web site project?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to use the config transformation files with a regular web site project (not a web application project)? I setup continuous builds in TFS and was wondering if it would still pick up the different config types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No- transforms are web app specific.

What we do is have three copies of web.config- one for each release type and then do our best to keep them all in sync.  Granted, a bit more work when modifying web.config; however, it does have a clear separation of content which can help when quickly scanning through config.

We have:

- Web.config
- Web.config.dev.exclude
- Web.config.rel.exclude

And reference in the appropriate file during the build using:

```
<!-- Copy the development configuration file so that it is picked up by the build machine. -->
<Copy SourceFiles="$(SolutionRoot)\$(SuiteSourceBranchRoot)\Source\Web\Company.Web\Web.config.rel.exclude" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\_PublishedWebsites\Company.Web\Web.config" />
<Copy SourceFiles="$(SolutionRoot)\$(SuiteSourceBranchRoot)\Source\Web\Company.Web\Web.config.rel.exclude" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\_PublishedWebsites\Company.Web.Setup\Web.config" />
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I used to do. I ended up converting my site to an application. Not just for that reason, though.

Comment: I can't stand having to build in order to test a change.  It is going to take a small miracle for me to ever consider using a web app :)